# How do you set a the buttons in a UIToolbar for subview of Navigation Controller application using Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I have a navigation-based iPhone app that goes down 3 levels deep currently. The MainWindow nib has inside of the Navigation Controller a navigation bar, toolbar, and a reference to the Root View Controller which has the toolbar items and navigation items inside of it in the hierarchy of stuff in the nib file. My other view controllers are located in other nibs. How can I add items to the toolbar that appear in the toolbar when I drill down to other views using Interface Builder? I know it's possible to do it programmatically like this:

```
nextViewController.toolbarItems = arrayOfToolbarItems;
```

However, it seems like there should be a way to do this in Interface Builder. This shouldn't be a terribly uncommon task, so I'd like to improve my understanding of how to use IB for future reference.

Comment: What prevents you from dragging instances of UIBarButtonItem onto your toolbar in IB?

Comment: The toolbar only exists in the MainWindow nib's Navigation Controller. I can't drag UIBarButtonItem objects that I need to show up the toolbar in other nibs for when those other controllers are pushed by the RootViewController.